# How to make a 3D scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot, matplotlib-3d

I am currently have a nx3 matrix array. I want plot the three columns as three axis's.
How can I do that?

I have googled and people suggested using **Matlab**, but I am really having a hard time with understanding it. I also need it be a scatter plot.

Comment: Are you looking for an application to do the plot, or do you want to write code (in whatever language) that draws the plot?

Comment: Use asymptote - it is free, powerful, and the quality is awesome!

Comment: If you have an array, I'd assume you have a program and this array is part of it. Please give us a chance to help you by indicating what kind of program (language) it is!

Comment: I would still use asymptote (as a lib), or just generate the input file for it. Check out it's amazing output quality!

Comment: If it's an `n` by 3 array, you will get a plot of a curve in 3 dimensions.  For a "3-d plot", you would need an `n x m x l` array.  Do you want a curve, with any one tuple `(x,y,z)` representing a point on the curve?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You can use [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/index.html) for this. matplotlib has a [mplot3d](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html) module that will do exactly what you want.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

sequence_containing_x_vals = list(range(0, 100))
sequence_containing_y_vals = list(range(0, 100))
sequence_containing_z_vals = list(range(0, 100))

random.shuffle(sequence_containing_x_vals)
random.shuffle(sequence_containing_y_vals)
random.shuffle(sequence_containing_z_vals)

ax.scatter(sequence_containing_x_vals, sequence_containing_y_vals, sequence_containing_z_vals)
plt.show()
```

The code above generates a figure like:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. Note that `plt.zlabel('zlabel')` wont work. To label the z axis you need to use: `ax.set_zlabel('Z')`.

Comment: instead of from matplotlib.pyplot
it should be import matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: @roktim Good spot.  The previous editor made that mistake in formatting the post which I've now corrected.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Just to add onto this, I also wanted my 3D scatterplot to rotate (I needed a gif of this), and found this [blog post](http://blog.mahler83.net/2019/10/rotating-3d-t-sne-animated-gif-scatterplot-with-matplotlib/)  that described how to do it with the solution you listed

Answer (score 16):

Use the following code it worked for me:

```
# Create the figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Generate the values
x_vals = X_iso[:, 0:1]
y_vals = X_iso[:, 1:2]
z_vals = X_iso[:, 2:3]

# Plot the values
ax.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, z_vals, c = 'b', marker='o')
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis')

plt.show()
```

while X_iso is my 3-D array and for X_vals, Y_vals, Z_vals I copied/used 1 column/axis from that array and assigned to those variables/arrays respectively.

Answer (score 7):

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
```

**scatter plot**

```
zdata = 15 * np.random.random(100)
xdata = np.sin(zdata) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(100)
ydata = np.cos(zdata) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(100)
ax.scatter3D(xdata, ydata, zdata);
```

[image]

[Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/04.12-Three-Dimensional-Plotting.ipynb#scrollTo=UWxW5wK_Gn-U)

Answer (score 1):

Using plotly - Easiest and most functional and nice plots

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
              color='species')
fig.show()
```

https://plotly.com/python/3d-scatter-plots/

Comment: Agreed, if all you want is a 3D plot, plotly is the simplest and cleanest solution.